# The effect that applying a nodal slide has on the fibers above the eigenline

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

So recently I've come across the following question posed to me by myself. Suppose I have an almost toric fibration that was obtained from a Delzant polyope by applying a nodal trade. Now in this nodal trade opperation what we are doing is replacing the standard Delzant corner by a copy of the Auroux system which is given in by $H_c=(H^c_1,H_2):\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, where $H^c_1(z_1,z_2)=|z1z2-c|^2$, $H_2(z_1,z_2)=\frac{1}{2}(|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2)$ and $c>0$. The focus-focus fiber is $H_c^{-1}(c^2,0)$. Now varying the value of $c$ when doing this replacement is what is known as a nodal slide. My question is the following. Suppose that I am doing a nodal slide where I am increasing the value of $c$. Let $p$ be a point in the base of my almost toric fibration that sits in the eigenline created by a nodal trade, let $\Delta_c$ be the initial almost toric fibration for the nodal trade and $\Delta_{c'}$ with $c'>c$ be the another one which is obtained by applying a nodal slide to $\Delta_c$. My question is that if the fiber over $p$ in $\Delta_c$ is Ham. isotopic or symplectomorphic to the fiber over $p$ in $\Delta_{c'}$?

So I belive this problem can be dealt with just by considering the different Auroux systems in $\mathbb{C}^2$. In this case I belive we can build said Hamiltonian isotopy. So first consider the conic fibration $\pi:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that sends $(z_1,z_2)\rightarrow z_1z_2$. The only singular point is the $0$. But what we are looking at are the follwing fibers $H_c^{-1}(d^2,0)$ and $H_{c'}^{-1}(d^2,0)$ where $c'>c>d$. Now $(H_1^{c})^{-1}(d^2)$ is the union of all conics living
over a circle $C_d$ of radius $d$ centred at $c$ and $(H_1^{c'})^{-1}(d^2)$ is is the union of all conics living
over a circle $C'_d$ of radius $d$ centred at $c'$. Hence what changes here is the center and so first we can see that over $\mathbb{C}$ one can build a Hamiltonian isotopy $\Phi_H^t$ from $H:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ doing a translation between these two circles and then use the fact that one can find a neighborhood of these two submanifolds in $\mathbb{C}^2$ where this $\pi$ is basically a projection, since we won't be over the singular point $0$, and then define a Hamiltonian $H\circ \pi : \mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, with the help of a partition of unity
to be able to extend it , that gives us the desired result.

I am interested in hearing other peoples input on this. Any insight is appreaciated. Thanks in advance.